# Reputation breakdown

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a way to see how much of your reputation has been earned from the various activities? So its broken down into the points for what you have asked, what you have answered, and the other ways you can earn points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no page that shows a tidy breakdown, but there is a kinda-hidden page that can give you all the raw daily data:

- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/reputation

As far as I know there's no direct link to that from any part of the site; you just have to remember that adding `/reputation` to the main site's URL can get you there. Browsing that (or analysing it with some coding skills) can give you an idea of where each point has come from.

A page of reports would be nice though, yes.

Comment: I had looked around and couldnt find one so I was pretty sure. But its easy to miss things sometimes. I didnt know about your link, so thanks.